# How do I make a MS VS C++ project standalone?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, exe

So I wrote a small script to do some math calculations, but I cant get it to run on another computer. When I try to run it, it says I'm missing multiple dlls. MSVCP140D.dll, VCRUNTIME.dll, and ucrtbased.dll are the ones it says it cant find. The only include I have in the entire doc is iostream, is it somehow linked to specific Visual Studios dlls? and if so how would I go about making it able to run on a different computer.

I am using VS 2019 and windows 10 if that helps in any way.

any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Don't deploy the debug build.  As long as the project has no dependency on libraries then you can use Project > Properties > switch to the Release configuration > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library = /MT

Answer (score 0):

You can use static linking of the C Runtime (`/MTd` or `/MT`), but it's not recommended in general which is why all VC++ projects default to the DLL version of the CRT (`/MDd` or `/MD`).

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170).